# frameworks with built-in jquery support?

Tags: jquery, frameworks

whenever i want to use jquery i just include it in the html header and then use it in my javascript files.

so what do people mean when they say that a framework got built-in jquery support?

and the same thing goes with ajax-support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frameworks provide actual implementations of common functions that are needed by many application. Built In jQuery support would imply that the framework may use jQuery to implement some of its functionality. Or it could simply imply that the links to the relevant jQuery files are provided.

Same for AJAX, the framework may implement a form submission via AJAX function so that as the user of the framework you may not have to write the code yourself but use the framework's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what you mean by framework.

For example, in Groovy+Grails you can use jQuery or Prototype. Grails will automatically add the script tag for jQuery to your pages. Grails also supports AJAX. There are specific Grails Tags that makes it easier for you to do AJAX-y stuff.

In Java, I believe the Spring framework has a module called "Spring Javascript" that's based on dojo.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is an official definition, but it usually means that the markup that the server side control/widget spits out will be compatible with the markup that the client side script library that creates the interactions. In otherwords, the back end system and front end system are coordinated so that they are both looking for and using the same html/css markup.

ASP.net has been embracing jQuery more and more. I know the IDEs fully support it. I can't say how 'integrated' the actual library is with the .net framework, though.